# Using features new API on app with old API

Tags: java, android

I have app with API 5. I want add some features for phone that have Android 3.0 or later. 
But i want app works on phone with API 5. (and new features use only for users with Android 3.0 or later).
What are the solutions?

Comment: there is no API 5 but there is Android 1.5

Comment: For Android 1.6 compatibility you can use android-support-v4 library.

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries available just to enable u to use some of the features of android 3.0 or later.  The most prominent one is using Fragments from Android 3.0

this link should help u: [Support libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any libraries that will support API level 5, however there is the android support library which works for API Level 6 and above.

[android-support-v4.jar](https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

I am curious tho, why use level 5? is your app used by those Andorid OS versions still? last time i checked even level 6 (android 1.6) had about 1% percent of the google play apps used. i can imagine 1.5 would be even lower than that.

I suggest moving your app to at least minimumTargetSDK to Android 1.6